# Checkbox and sharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

I am using a grid view for a movie app. When the user clicks on a movie, details of the movie are revealed. Inside this new activity, the user can mark the movie as favorite. I'm using sharedPreferences to store the state of the checkbox when checked or unchecked. The problem is that, when i go back to the grid view to choose another movie to mark it as favorite, all the movies in the grid view show marked as favorite even though i did not explicitly check these movies. Please, what could be responsible for this behavior? Below is my detail activity code:

```
public class MovieDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SHARED_PF_NAME = "movieSP";
    private static final String CHECK_BOX_STATE = "check_state";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    CheckBox checkBox;



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movie Details");

        /*//get values passed from main
        movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.MOVIE_IN_CURRENT_CLICKED_POSITION);

        // get movie id of the movie that was just passed
        final int movieIdOfMovieInCurrentlyClicked= movie.getMovieid();

        //get path for trailer and reviews
        String movieVideoPath = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieIdOfMovieInCurrentlyClicked+ "/videos?api_key=" + MovieDataSource.API_KEY;
        String movieReviewPath = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/" + movieIdOfMovieInCurrentlyClicked + "/reviews?api_key=" + MovieDataSource.API_KEY;
        // initiate asynctask
        new MovieTrailerAsyncTask().execute(movieVideoPath);
        new MovieReviewAsyncTask().execute(movieReviewPath);

        // trailer recycler
        trailerRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.trailers_RecyclerView);
        trailerRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        trailerRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(trailerLinearLayoutManager);
        movieTrailerRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieTrailerRecyclerViewAdapter(MovieDetails.this, movieTrailerArrayList);
        trailerRecyclerview.setAdapter(movieTrailerRecyclerViewAdapter);



        //reviews recycler
        reviewRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reviews_recyclerview);
        trailerRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        reviewRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(reviewLinearLayoutManager);
        movieReviewRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieReviewRecyclerViewAdapter(MovieDetails.this, movieReviewsArrayList);
        reviewRecyclerView.setAdapter(movieReviewRecyclerViewAdapter);







        TextView movieTitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
        ImageView movieImageView = findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        TextView movieReleaseDateView = findViewById(R.id.movieReleaseDate);
        TextView movieRatingView = findViewById(R.id.movieRating);
        TextView movieDescriptionView = findViewById(R.id.movieDescription);





        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(movie.getMovieImagePath())
                .fit()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_file)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .into(movieImageView);

        movieTitleTextView.setText(movie.getMovieTitle());
        movieReleaseDateView.setText(movie.getMovieReleaseDate());
        movieRatingView.setText(String.format("%s%s", String.valueOf(movie.getMovieRating()), ratingDenominator));
        movieDescriptionView.setText(movie.getMovieDescripton());
*/
        checkBox= findViewById(R.id.checkbox_button);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



            checkBox.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK_BOX_STATE, false));



            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(CHECK_BOX_STATE, isChecked).apply();

                if (isChecked){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not checked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }




            }
        });




    }
```

Grid view Adapter:

```
    public class MovieDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movies;

    MovieDisplayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movies = movies;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        Log.i("count",String.valueOf(movies.size()));
        return movies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movies.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else

        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(movies.get(position).getMovieImagePath())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_file)
                .fit()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView); // View where image is loaded.


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

MainActivity(intent code):

```
gridView.setAdapter(new MovieDisplayAdapter(MainActivity.this, movies));
                    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            movieIdOfMovieInCurrentlyClicked = movies.get(position).getMovieid();
                            moviePosition = position;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MovieDetails.class);
                            //When clicked, the position of the current movie
                            Movie movieIncurrentClickedPosition = movies.get(moviePosition);
                            intent.putExtra(MOVIE_IN_CURRENT_CLICKED_POSITION, movieIncurrentClickedPosition);

                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Post your code of grid view adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a single variable (`CHECK_BOX_STATE`) to store the `favorite` status of all the movies, rather than storing the `favorite` status for each movie. You need to create a different boolean entry in the `SharedPreferences` for each favourite movie, and then remove it when the movie is no longer favourite.

```
public class MovieDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String SHARED_PF_NAME = "favoriteMovies";
    private Movie movie; // I'm guessing the class name is Movie
    private CheckBox checkBox;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_details);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Movie Details");

        movie = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
            MainActivity.MOVIE_IN_CURRENT_CLICKED_POSITION);
        final String key = Integer.toString(movie.getMovieId());

        // all the other stuff...

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox_button);
        checkBox.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false));
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(key, true).apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "checked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    sharedPreferences.edit().remove(key).apply();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not checked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now just the way i want it.  Thanks for  the explanation too.

Answer (score -1):

the thing here is that you are saving a single check state, so when you try to retrieve that checkstate is just one, you have to filter each of the checkStates by an identifier for each of the movies...
as an additional comment is better to store that information in the movies object in a local database so you just do a simple query to update and retrieve that state